# Hibernate FileZippedJarVisitor error in test jar

Tags: java, hibernate, maven

I have a structure more or less like this:

```
-- ProjectA
+-- ProjectA Persistence
+-- ProjectA EJBs
+- ProjectB
+-- lots of ProjectB children...
```

Supposing that in `ProjectB` I want to write some tests. So, I setup OpenEJB for this job, and it was working, but then I needed some EJBs from `ProjectA EJBs`.

As OpenEJB was not loading the EJBs from `ProjectA`(even if it is a dependency of `ProjectB`), I add the `ProjectA EJBS` as a dependency for `ProjectB` in `test` scope.

As `ProjectA EJBs` dependent on `ProjectA Persistence`, looks like Hibernate tries to load it... but it does some weird things.

Hibernate `FileZippedJarVisitor` tries to extract something like: `~/.m2/repository/com/example/projecta/1.0.0/projecta-ejbs-1.0.0.jar/project-persistence-1.0.0.jar` instead of `~/.m2/repository/com/example/projecta/1.0.0/projecta-persistence-1.0.0.jar`.

What can I do about that?
Sorry if my explanation was not good enough, please ask me more info if you need.

Comment: Could you post example poms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reported it as bug, which was rejected for lack of response.

https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-8227

Answer (score 1):

As you described, `ProjectA Persistence` is a dependency and maven is trying to download it from your m2 repository.

To build `ProjectA Persistence` and send it to your m2 repository you may run:

*`mvn install`*

Comment: You get it wrong (or I explain wrong). This error is because of the `persistence.xml` `jar-file` notation. As I add the `ProjectA`, and it contains the `ProjectA Persistence`, it tries to get the jar from the wrong place. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry about the misunderstanding. Show us your `pom.xml`'s

Comment: the issue in Hibernate FileZippedJarVisitor. I already open a bug in their JIRA. Thanks anyway.

Comment: glad you found the problem. post an answer pointing the opened bug ticket and accept it as the correct one.